# WPF Binding ComboBox (withing a ListView Column) to an ItemSource outside of the ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox, textbox

I've tried a lot already...

My View contain two ListViews - ListView ShiftH and ListView ShiftT. In ListView ShiftT is a column with a ComboBox.

I want the ComboBox to display a value of ShiftH. When this value got chosen the user can add the model (the row) to the list (resp. store it in the db). The ShiftT record holds now the ID of the ShiftH record.

Now I want the ComboBox, when the list is initially loaded, to present the corresponding discription of the ShiftH record which is to find in the ShiftH List.

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">
                    Schichtdetails
                </Label>

                <ListView x:Name="ShiftT" MinHeight="150" MaxHeight="200" MinWidth="500" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource DifAlternationColorsLV}"
                          AlternationCount="2"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding UiShiftTModelList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        
                        <GridView>
                          
                            <GridView.Columns>

                             <GridViewColumn Header="SchichtID" Width="60">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="SelectedShiftHID"
                                            SelectedIndex="{Binding SchichtID}"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="Bezeichnung"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UiShiftHModelList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type vms:TimeStampConfigShiftViewModel}}}"/>
                                            
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                         </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Before and after the ComboBox are some more columns.... but anyway when I bind it like this... the CB shows nada and throws binding errors

If I bind like this:

```
                                      <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="SelectedShiftHID"
                                                SelectedIndex="{Binding SchichtID}"
                                                DisplayMemberPath="Bezeichnung"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.UiShiftHModelList, Mode=OneWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
```

The ComboBox is loading the values from ShiftH and initialize correct...
[image]

but is throwing binding errors:

- System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MKDesktopUI.ViewModels.TimeStamp.TimeStampConfigShiftViewModel', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=UiShiftHModelList; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='SelectedShiftHID'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
- System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.UiShiftHModelList; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='SelectedShiftHID'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

I don't get it...

Comment: The first approach makes obviously no sense, because a view model can never be an ancestor of a view element. It is not even part of a logical or visual tree. The second approach seems to be ok, but setting `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. The Binding is inherently OneWayUpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Okay, got that - makes sense! Any tips how to set the Binding for the SchichtID (its not part of the ItemSource but from the ListView)